# Logging sshfs reads + writes - Possible?

Tags: logging, sshfs, write

We use sshfs in quite a few situations.

We were wondering if there was a way to log the read / writes made to the sshfs mounts we have so we could optimize things on our local side (eg: tweaking cache, locally caching objects, etc).

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if there are sshfs logging functions.. but you could probably get a good amount of change info running something like AIDE or tripwire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sshfs` is a client application, it uses `sftp` on the server side. Have a look at the manual pages of `sftp-server(8)` and `sshd_config(5)`.

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, you should put something like (not sure if quotes are needed, try it yourself):

```
Subsystem sftp "/usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server -l INFO"
```

This will log details using the AUTH facility (`/var/log/auth.log` on Debian with rsyslogd). To separate SFTP logs from regular authentication messages, you can specify a different facility or redirect the logs. For rsyslogd, you can create `/etc/rsyslog.d/sftp.conf` containing:

```
:programname,isequal,"sftp-server" /var/log/sftp.log
```

Note that if your sftp user is chrooted, you need to create a `/dev/log` socket such that sftp can send messages to the syslog daemon. For rsyslogd, this can be done by creating the `dev` directory and adding the following line to `sftp.conf`:

```
$AddUnixListenSocket /home/user/dev/log
```